# Google Places Radar Search: file_get_contents() delivers more results than a browser

Tags: php, url, search, google-places-api

i was working with Google's Radar Search, and i got a strange behaviour:

The URL

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=48.859294,2.347589&radius=5000&types=food|cafe&keyword=vegetarian&key=[mygooglekey]

has 9 Results. See here:
http://pastebin.com/fEH3Es0Q

With this code, with the same URL:

```
<?php 
$radarurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=48.859294,2.347589&radius=5000&types=food|cafe&keyword=vegetarian&key=[mygooglekey]";
$json = file_get_contents($radarurl);
$radar = json_decode($json);
print_r($radar);
?>
```

i get 77 Results. See here:
http://www.giwaco.de/test.php

:/

```
Adrian
```

Comment: the radar search should return up to 200 results... I get `{
   "error_message" : "The provided API key is invalid.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}` when visit your link

Comment: Hi Webinan, create a Google API Key and paste it instead of [mygooglekey] in the URL. Sorry, i cannot provide my own key to test. You can create one at https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't noticed that :/
 Anyway `403. That’s an error.

We're sorry, but this service is not available in your country.` :D

Comment: OFFTOP: @AdrianGier when you got an array of the Radar search results, how you did get all info about each place? Radar search results have only `place_id` and other identifiers but no any human readable info for each place like `name` or `address`. How you get this info?

Comment: @artuska: with geonames api  e.g.: http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName?lat=47.3&lng=9&username=demo